# What is the reason of using 'CHAR' with DATATYPE SIZE when declaring variable

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, sqldatatypes

## WHY THE 'CHAR' IS USING WITH SIZE ?

```
declare
  lf  constant varchar2(1 char) := chr(10);
  lf2 constant varchar2(2 char) := lf || lf;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('LINE-X'||lf||'LINE-Y'||lf2||'LINE-Z');
end;
```

RESULT IS FINE AS BELOW

LINE-X
LINE-Y

LINE-Z

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

## AND IF IT IS POSIBLE WHICH SINARIO WE CAN USE 'CHAR'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a `varchar2` datatype variable (or column), you have two options when setting its size: `char` and `byte`:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (a    varchar2(1 byte),
  3     b    varchar2(2 char)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

The first option (`byte`) means that you *reserved* exactly one byte for that column.

The second option (`char`) means that you chose to store one **character** into that column. In many/most cases, there's no difference. But, if you use character set that contains **multibyte characters**, you can't tell how many bytes will each character occupy so - for example - `varchar2(2 byte)` doesn't guarantee that you'll manage to store all characters (for example the one that uses 3 bytes won't fit).

Comment: Can I contact u outside of this like a phone conversation @littlefoot

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I'm unavailable.